# Java int 'through' int operator?

Tags: java, operators

I'm trying to figure out how to do something like:

```
int test = 1;
int test1 = 10;
if (value = test (though) test1) {
}
```

I've looked at oracles java operators but could not figure out how to do it.
The construct should check if `value` is between `test` and `test1`.

Can anybody tell me how to do this in Java?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you looking for a loop?

Comment: better explain it in plain English ;)

Comment: if a players inventory contains more than the maximum integer & they pick up an item of the same id that it will tell them their inventory is full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (value >= test && value <= test1)
{
    //doSomething
}
```

Java does not support chained inequalities, ie `test <= value <= test1`, so instead you can just use two boolean expressions, connected via the boolean and operator, to get a logically equivalent conditional.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like with **logical and** operator

```
    if (value > test && value < test1) {
     // do something
    }
```

or add >=  to add equals comparison too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for `range` operator that is common in a lot of programming languages, Java not being one of them, but the condition that you are trying to impose on the range will always be the same. You don't need to check *every* value in the range, merely the endpoints since it is contiguous:

```
if( value > test && value < test1 ) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Exactly What I'm looking for. Thank you sir. Will make correct answer in 10 mins due to inability to do so at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `through` op in Java. You can do it with a simple `if` :

```
if (value >= test && value <= test1) {
     // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This post begged to be clarified.

If you are checking that `value` is between test1 and test2 then you need:

```
if(value >= test && value <= test1){
   // do stuff
}
```

Note that you should remove the `=` signs if `value` should be strictly between test and test1.

However, if you are checking that `value` is one of multiple tests from test0 "through" test10 for instance, then pack those tests in a set and check if value is among them:

```
import java.util.*;

Set tests = new HashSet();
tests.add(test);
tests.add(test1); // similarly for as many as you need

if(tests.contains(value)){
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is for people who end up looking for the second type of "through" as the kind of solution.